# Linked image is not clickable in iOS 6, but text is

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I've run into an issue where my iOS 6 device (iPhone) is unable to click icons generated by javascript. I've been debugging for too many hours, but it seems the click/vclick events are not even firing. You can't even get the CSS :active state to light up with the images (sometimes you can for just milliseconds, but it still doesn't register a JS click).

I set the event to use mouseover just to test, and that actually worked - although inconsistently. it's as if the bounds of the  element are incorrect.

The icons themselves look fine, you just can't click on them.

I added some text to the button, which spill below the image. **This added text IS clickable**. So it all is working, but for some reason the images don't register a click event. I think this might even be a CSS issue. It doesn't matter if the text comes before or after (proving that the menu bar background is not the issue).

There is nothing special about the images. They are just an `<img>` tag, display: block, with a set width/height. I gave the images `cursor: pointer` because I read that will fix it. It doesn't.

---

The generated HTML:

```
<div id="menubar">
  <div class="menu-icon-group clearfix">

    <a class="menu-icon icon-add-woman ui-link" data-page="add-woman">
      <img src="images/icons/add-woman-132-w.png" alt="" class="menuicon-normal">
      <img src="images/icons/add-woman-132-b.png" alt="" class="menuicon-active">
      <span style="color:#000; border:1px solid #f00">Test</span>
    </a>

    <a class="menu-icon icon-panel ui-link">
      <img src="images/icons/panel-132-w.png" alt="" class="menuicon-normal">
      <img src="images/icons/panel-132-b.png" alt="" class="menuicon-active">
      <span style="color:#000; border:1px solid #f00">Test</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#menubar .menu-icon-group img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menubar .menu-icon-group { float: right; }
#menubar .menu-icon { float: left; }

#menubar .menu-icon img.menuicon-active { display: none; }
#menubar .menu-icon img.menuicon-normal { display: block; }

#menubar .menu-icon:active img.menuicon-normal { display: none; }
#menubar .menu-icon:active img.menuicon-active { display: block; }

#menubar .menu-icon:active {
  background: #ffff2a;
}
```

The JavaScript (Only applies to first link, second link has no data-page attribute):

```
// Clicked on a nav button that links to a page (by data-page property)
$(document).on('click vclick', '#menubar .menu-icon', function(e) {
  alert('Menu icon clicked!');

  var page_key = $(this).attr('data-page');
  if ( !page_key ) return;

  var the_page = get_page( page_key );
  if ( the_page.filename ) {
    $('body').pagecontainer( 'change', the_page.filename );
  }
});
```

Comment: See if it works with opacity:0 instead of display:none, then adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Christina That does work, actually... Which is very weird. One of the two icons was set to be visible at a time. I guess I'll need to re-work the code to support this. If you want to post as an answer, I'll accept it. This does seem to identify the bug. Thanks.

Comment: As an off-topic sidenote, you're better off combining all those icons into a single sprite then using `background-image` instead. Saving those extra http requests definitely helps.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration. This will be packaged as an app at some point, with local file references. I'm not worried about the HTTP requests/bandwidth/etc in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. I have not used display:none in years for this type of thing because IOS has something about not honoring click events on something that doesn't exist.

I generally use `opacity:0;overflow:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;` as my new display:none and then reverse on the toggled state.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. The code I supplied started with `.menuicon-normal` being display:block. This image is then set to `display: none` when you click it, via CSS. This action interrupts the click event, even though the `<a>` element is still present and a new image takes its place. It seems weird that the event does not even bubble to the containing `<a>` element though. And stranger still that the "hiding" trick works, since technically it's the same behavior - the element you clicked on is no longer there. Oh well, this works. Thanks!

Comment: This the article from a couple years ago about :hover but it's similar if you use visibility:hidden OR display:none the tapped element stops working or doesn't work to start depending on the situation. http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/ -- it doesn't say in the article but my response was to use opacity:0 and other css so that it's gone, but not gone.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This makes sense now. I also found a comment on that quotes Apple's documentation: _"if the contents of the page changes on the mousemove event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent."_ (Thanks for the quote, Dave Methvin)